# What did I do wrong?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So, I have found the following problem. This problem is a multiple-choice one, and I have to pick the correct answer. The problem, gives a function $f:D \to R$, $$f(x)=\frac{xe^x}{e^x-a}$$ with $a$ being a real number.

I have managed to proof that if $a \in (0,1)$, the function is strictly increasing. I will describe how.

If $a \in (0,1)$, the function is well defiend for all real numbers, except $\ln{a}$.

The derivate is:
$$f'(x)=e^x\frac{e^x-a-ax}{(e^x-a)^2}$$

To study its sign we only need to study the sign of $g(x) = e^x-a-ax$. Since $$g'(x)=e^x-a$$ I have found that $g(x)>0$, and $x_0=-a\ln{a}$ it's a minimum point.

It follows that $f'(x)>0$, and hence f is strictly increasing.

So, what's the mistake in my reasoning..?

Comment: Compare $f(\ln a - \varepsilon)$ to $f(\ln a + \varepsilon)$ for a small $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: Yeah. What does the exercises want to show?

Comment: It was a multiple-choice problem. Basically I had to check multiple variants to see which one was true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mistake in your reasoning is that the domain of $f$ is not connected. $f$ has a pole at $\ln a$, and

$$\lim_{x\uparrow \ln a} f(x) = +\infty,\quad \lim_{x\downarrow \ln a} f(x) = -\infty.$$

The strict positivity of the derivative says that $f$ is strictly increasing on every interval contained in its domain, but it does not say anything about the values at points on different sides of a "hole" in the domain.

Comment: How could I be so stupid...thank you..